# How can retrieve email address from the Infopath people/Group picker

Tags: infopath

How can retrieve email address from the Infopath people/Group picker?When I add the people/Group picker into the infopath form, I only get 3 fields DisplayName,AccountId,AccountType.Can anyone show me how can I get the email either by configurations or by code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the UserProfileService using the accountid from your people picker.

I wrote a simple class to do this from my form's code behind. Here's a quick sample with just the relevent bits (I'm typing from memory as I don't have the code in front of me, but you should be able to figure it out)...

First, add a web reference to your machine's UserProfileService

http://[your server]/_vti_bin/userprofileservice.asmx

Then...

```
class UserInfo
{
    private UPSvc.UserProfileService _svc = null;
    private UPSvc.PropertyData[] _pData = null; 
    private string _domainLogin = string.Empty;
    public WorkEmail = string.Empty;

    public UserInfo( string domainLogin )
    {
        _domainLogin = domainLogin;
        _svc = new UPSvc.UserProfileService();
        _svc.UseDefaultCredentials  = true;
        _pData = _svc.GetUserProfileByName( domainLogin );

        int WORK_EMAIL = GetIndexOfProperty( "WorkEmail" );
        WorkEmail = GetADValue( WORK_EMAIL );

    }

    private string GetADValue( int idx )
    {
        return _pData[ idx ].Values[0].Value.ToString();
    }

    private int GetIndexOfProperty( string propertyName )
    {
        for( int i=0; i<_pData.Length; i++ )
        {
            if( _pData[i].Name.CompareTo( propertyName ) == 0 )
                    return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

To call...

UserInfo ui = new UserInfo( "domain\username" );
string email = ui.WorkEmail;

Hope that helps!

Cheers,
Bob